# jQuery ajax using success event, how to get json properties

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Doing a `jquery` ajax request using the `success` event:

```
     $.ajax("/subscribe/email", {
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                email: $("#e").val()
            },
            success: function(result) {
                console.log(result.err);
            }
     });
```

The problem is `result.err` is undefined, yet the response is `json` and has this property.

```
{
   "err": "Some error message goes here."
}
```

How do I access properties of the javascript object via `result`.

Comment: Use `console.log(result);` it will show all properties in the object

Comment: Are you sure that's the json that is returned? Because it works here: http://jsfiddle.net/DBswc/

Comment: Also, check your network tab in the browser's development tools. Confirm the MIME type of your response.

Comment: May be on you server side, set response type to `application/json`

Comment: I confirmed that on the server the content-type is `application/json`. Still `result.err` is undefined.

Comment: @Justin if result.json is undefined, your error is on the server. Could you post the code that sends the result.  You don't need to parse the json like some have suggested as sending datatye json expects a json back.

Comment: in the success callback can you try `console.log(JSON.stringify(result));`

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to parse the json. Modern browsers can do:

```
JSON.parse(result).err
```

Or using jQuery:

```
$.parseJSON(result).err
```